# Docker on Windows: how to increase volume size?

Tags: windows, docker, volume

I'm running Docker on Windows, using Linux containers, without docker-compose.
I created a volume to be mounted on my container:

`docker volume create my_volume`

While my container is running, it fills the volume with data.
After filling the volume with about 2.369 GB (value retrieved through command `docker system df -v`), it is full and the container cannot write on it anymore (error say: "No space left on disk").

Is there a way to increase the space of a volume, or to specify its size at creation time?

Note that the host has much more free disk space (about 80GB).

Also, for performance reasons, I don't want to mount a host's directory to the container.

Update:
I attempted to specify the volume size at creation time:

```
docker volume create --opt type=tmpfs --opt device=tmpfs --opt o=size=60000000000 my_volume
```

(Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/ )
but, even if the disk looks 60GB large, no more than 2.4GB can be written.